# Inner join within update statement in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have table called temp_table which consist of following rows:

```
 cola colb result
 ----------------
  p4   s1    0
  p8   s1    0
  p9   s1    0
  p5   f1    0
  p8   f1    0
```

Now I need to update result column with the count(*) of colb. For which i am trying the following query:

```
update tem_table
set result = x.result
from tem_table tt
inner join(select colb,count(*) as result from tem_table group by colb) x
on x.colb = tt.colb;
```

And selecting distinct colb and result from temp_table:

```
select distinct colb,result from tem_table;
```

Getting output:

```
colb result
-----------
 s1    3
 f1    3
```

But the expected output is:

```
colb result
-----------
 s1    3
 f1    2
```

I am not getting where I am getting wrong in my query? Please help me.Thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You should not repeat the table to be updated in the `from` clause. This will create a cartesian self join.

Quote from the manual:

> *Note that the target table **must not appear in the from_list**, unless you intend a self-join (in which case it must appear with an alias in the from_list)*

<sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

Unfortunately `UPDATE` does not support  explicit joins using the `JOIN` keyword. Something like this should work:

```
update tem_table
  set result = x.result
from (
    select colb,count(*) as result 
    from tem_table 
    group by colb
) x
where x.colb = tem_table.colb;
```